# sj:select not setting default text for second sj:select

Tags: jquery, struts2-jquery

I have two sj:select where when i am selecting some value from first sj :select the second should get populated with some value which corresponds to retrieve based on selection of first value. The problem which i am facing is that whenever i am selecting the first value the second dropdown is getting populated but it is showing header text as first value which i dont want i want the corresponding value should be selected in the second sj:select.

```
     <s:url id="buttontypeurl" action="fetchButtonTypes" />
                 <sj:select href="%{buttontypeurl}" id="buttonType" 
                            name="uiElement.buttonType" list="mstrButtonTypes" listKey="name" listValue="value"
                            onChangeTopics="reloaddestlist"  onCompleteTopics="reloaddestlist" reloadTopics="reloadFirstlist"
                            headerKey="-1" headerValue="%{getText('uiElementSearch.option.label.pleaseSelectType')}"  cssClass="form-control search-val"
                             />


     <s:url id="displayareaurl" action="fetchAreas" />
                 <sj:select href="%{displayareaurl}" id="displayArea" 
                  formIds="uiElementSrchForm"   onChangeTopics="reloadFirstlist" reloadTopics="reloaddestlist" name="uiElement.area" list="mstrAreas" 
                  listKey="name" listValue="value" cssClass="form-control search-val" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--%{getText('uiElement.option.label.SelectArea')}--"  
                            tooltip="%{getText('search.label.area.info')}" />
```

whenever i am selecting any value from first sj:select i.e. buttonType for second sj:select the header value "--Select Display Area--" is coming as first value and then the corresponding area like 'Playback Screen' but i want the corresponding display area as selected means 'Playback Screen' should come as selected not the header text. Please help.

Comment: You could simple remove the attributes:
headerKey="-1" headerValue="--%{getText('uiElement.option.label.SelectArea')}--"

Comment: @jogep I need header also so I did it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this with iterating the options for select and with matching criteria i did $(option).prop("selected", true) for matching option value from second drop down.